# combine multiple dataframes to a list by storing variables in r

Tags: r, list

I have 3 dataframes:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "ID V1 V2 V3 V4
A 1 2 3 4
B 5 6 7 8
C 9 10 11 12", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "ID V1 V2 V3 V4
D 13 14 15 16
E 17 18 19 20
F 21 22 23 24", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)

df3 <- read.table(text = "ID V1 V2 V3 V4
G 25 26 27 28
H 29 30 31 32
I 33 34 35 35", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```

How can I combine these three dataframes into a list, not just using `list` function to combine them, but storing the variables.

When I look up a certain variable, I except to see them separated by dataframes I inputed, like if my list is called `test`:

```
test[[ID]]
df1 df2 df3
A D G
B E H
C F I

test[[V1]]
df1 df2 df3
1 13 25
5 17 29
9 21 33
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want - do you mean like `Map(data.frame, df1=df1, df2=df2, df3=df3)` ?

Comment: It's difficult to see why you would want to store the data in this way; it is not a very "R-like" solution. It would be more usual to store each data frame as a list item, or to combine the data frames into one with a column to identify the originals.

Comment: Problem solved, I will re consider my data structure, thanks a lot @neilfws

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I concur with @neilfws' sentiment in that this seems to be an unusual structure you would want. Perhaps you should take a step back and rethink what it is that you'd like to do with the data downstream and whether there is a better structure to work towards that goal.

That aside, you can generate such a structure in the following way

First off, store the individual `data.frame`s in a named `list`.

```
lst <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3)
```

Then the following reproduces your expected output

```
setNames(
    lapply(seq_along(lst[[1]]), function(idx) sapply(lst, function(x) x[, idx])),
    names(lst[[1]]))
#$ID
#     df1 df2 df3
#[1,] "A" "D" "G"
#[2,] "B" "E" "H"
#[3,] "C" "F" "I"
#
#$V1
#     df1 df2 df3
#[1,]   1  13  25
#[2,]   5  17  29
#[3,]   9  21  33
#
#$V2
#     df1 df2 df3
#[1,]   2  14  26
#[2,]   6  18  30
#[3,]  10  22  34
#
#$V3
#     df1 df2 df3
#[1,]   3  15  27
#[2,]   7  19  31
#[3,]  11  23  35
#
#$V4
#     df1 df2 df3
#[1,]   4  16  28
#[2,]   8  20  32
#[3,]  12  24  35
```

This assumes that all `data.frame`s have an identical column structure.

Comment: Thanks you very much, I will re-consider my purpose